# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unrecognized XSLTC extension 'http://saxon.sf.net/:assign'

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, nm

I keep getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unrecognized XSLTC extension 'http://saxon.sf.net/:assign'` when I run my xsl code through java.
The xsl declaration is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon redirect" version="2.0" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="saxon">
```

I am trying to use Saxon to increment a variable everytime flow enters a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error message saying `Unrecognized XSLTC extension` suggests that you are running Xalan XSLTC and not Saxon 9 to execute the stylesheet. There are different XSLT processors you can use with Java but for one stylesheet you can only use one at a time, so you will need to decide whether you want to use Saxon or Xalan and then you can use the extensions supported by the selected processor but not extensions supported by different processors.

Comment: In addition to this answer, if you explain what problem you are trying to solve, then we can probably help you solve it without using this Saxon extension, which is best avoided for at least two reasons: it makes your stylesheet non-portable, and it disables many Saxon optimizations.